# $(this).next().show(); not showing my next class

Tags: jquery

I want .itemholder to show when .folder is clicked. but only the .itemholder directly under the $(this) folder

```
 <img src="img.jpg" class="folder"/>
 <div class="itemholder"></div>
 <img src="img.jpg" class="folder"/>
 <div class="itemholder"></div>



 $('.itemholder').hide();
$('.folder').click(function(){
$(this).next('.itemholder').show();
});
```

why isnt this working?

Comment: Pls, provide code snippet or jsfiddle for this

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/ccynk8nx/2/

Comment: How do you debug it? Is the click event fired???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.nextAll()` with `:first` or `:eq(0)` selector to target next first element:

```
$(this).nextAll('.itemholder:first').show();
```

Comment: this resolved it, however i do not no why my statement didnt work.